# Select between TCP socket and UDP socket(c)

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp, udp

i'm making a server in c that handles both a tcp connection for an admin to change server configs and a udp connection to handle multiple clients

Here is my code:

```
    struct sockaddr_in si_minhaTCP,si_minhaUDP, si_outra;
    int nready, maxfdp1;
    int fdTcp;
    int fdUdp;
    fd_set rset;
    if (argc != 4) {
    printf("server {client port(udp)} {admin port(tcp)} {registry file path}\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

    fdTcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&si_minhaTCP, sizeof(si_minhaTCP));
    si_minhaTCP.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_minhaTCP.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    si_minhaTCP.sin_port = htons((short) atoi(argv[2]));
    bind(fdTcp, (struct sockaddr*)&si_minhaTCP, sizeof(si_minhaTCP));
    listen(fdTcp, 10);


        
    fdUdp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    si_minhaUDP.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_minhaUDP.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    si_minhaUDP.sin_port = htons((short) atoi(argv[1]));
    bind(fdUdp, (struct sockaddr*)&si_minhaUDP, sizeof(si_minhaUDP));


    FD_ZERO(&rset);

    maxfdp1 = max(fdTcp, fdUdp) + 1;
    for (;;)
    {
      FD_SET(fdTcp, &rset);
      FD_SET(fdUdp, &rset);
      // select the ready descriptor

      nready = select(maxfdp1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      if (FD_ISSET(fdTcp, &rset))
      {

          //handle tcp connection
      }
      if (FD_ISSET(fdUdp, &rset))
      {
          //handle udp connection
      }

    }
```

When i run this code, and try to test it with a udp client it doesnt do anything

Comment: In your actual code, you do have error checking (for the socket creation etc.)? And in the actual code you actually do something when there's traffic on the UDP socket?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i dont have erro checking but i do have code when there is traffic on the UDP socket, just could post here because the code limit

Comment: First of all have you tried to use any kind of debugging? Like printing out a message (with a trailing newline in the `printf` string) when `select` returns (and what it returns), and also printing a message for "handle udp connection". Does it work that far? Then the problem is in the code you don't show us. On the other hand, if the `select` doesn't return or `fdUdp` isn't set in `rset`, then the problem is most likely in your client.

Comment: Just curious: Are you using UDP to support multiple client as you said? FYI: TCP supports multiple client and is reliable. UDP is by design an unreliable protocol. Make sure you select the correct one.

Comment: I've added some error handling, and i'm getting a permission denied when binding the fdTcp, i'm using port 200 @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @fpiette its for an assignment where it asks to use udp to handle the clients

Comment: Ports below 1024 are *reserved* for system use, you need elevated privileges to be able to use such a port number. For applications you should use a port from 1024 and up. This is for both TCP and UDP.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that was the problem, i should have added error handling from the beginning, my fault, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However you can use ports below 1024 if you run the program as root and have no other programs running, that already use that ports...